# get primary and secondary site administrators using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I want to retrieve the primary and secondary site administrators using javascript and show them in the labels on custom Access Denied page. Using the code below(inline javascript) to do that but SP.SOD.ExcuteFunc() does not get executed. Am I missing something?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">


<script type="text/javascript">
    SP.SOD.RegisterSod("sp.js", "\_layouts\sp.js");
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

     debugger;
     alert("check");
     var clientContext;
     var siteCollection;

         SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAdmin);


         function getAdmin(){
             alert("Entering into function");
             var currentContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
             //alert("1");
             var siteColl = clientContext.get_site();
             var rootWeb = siteColl.get_rootWeb();
             this.props = rootWeb.get_allProperties();

             clientContext.load(rootWeb);
             clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
             //alert("end");
         }
         //alert("After");
         function onRequestSucceeded() 
         {
             alert("inside onrequest");
             var primarySiteContact = this.props.get_item('GA_PrimarySiteCollectionContact');
             var secondarySiteContact = this.props.get_item('GA_SecondarySiteCollectionContact');
             elem = document.getElementById('lblPrimary');
             elem.innerHTML = primarySiteContact;
             alert(primarySiteContact);
         }

         function onRequestFailed(sender, args) 
         {
             alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
         }

</script>
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
 <asp:Panel id="PanelUserName" runat="server">
 <tr>
    <td class="ms-sectionheader">
        <img src="/_layouts/images/ListSet.gif" alt="" />
        <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral ID="EncodedLiteral3" runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,accessDenied_currentuser%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="ms-descriptiontext"><SharePoint:EncodedLiteral ID="EncodedLiteral4" runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,accessDenied_loggedInAs%>" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode'/>
        &#160;<b><asp:Label id="LabelUserName" runat="server"/></b>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </asp:Panel>
 <tr>
    <td>&#160;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>

        <asp:HyperLink id="HLinkLoginAsAnother" Text="<%$SPHtmlEncodedResources:wss,accessDenied_logInAsAnotherOne%>"
            CssClass="ms-descriptiontext" runat="server"/>

        <br/>

        <asp:HyperLink id="HLinkRequestAccess" Text="<%$SPHtmlEncodedResources:wss,accessDenied_requestAccess%>"
            CssClass="ms-descriptiontext" runat="server" /><br /><br />
            <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please contact the below mentioned site owners" /><br/>
        <asp:Label id="lblPrimary" runat="server" /><br/>
        <asp:Label id="lblSecondary" runat="server" />
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: where is `SP` object? Please append code.

Comment: I have added "sp.js" file in my project and added the reference to the same as <script type="text/javascript">
    SP.SOD.RegisterSod("sp.js", "\_layouts\sp.js");
</script> in my HTML page

Comment: SP.js is in the layouts folder in the 14 hive folder also

Comment: `SP.SOD.RegisterSod` should be `SP.SOD.registerSod` but I doubt that that will resolve all your problems. What error message(s) do you see when you load the page with the F12 debugger console open?

Comment: No error messages. It does not seems to hit getAdmin function or in other words the excution simply jumps the following code SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAdmin);